How can I stop this layering from happening when I use sculpt tools?
How can I stop the sculpting tool from iuntersecting the Mesh when I use it?



This is just the nature of how sculpting works. All every sculpt brush is doing is moving the vertices of the mesh along the vertex normal (a direction vector pointing directly away from the mesh).
When geo starts to look like this it will inevitably intersect with itself.

Sculpting is always a battle between resolution and ease of management of the mesh. You can use any number of methods to find that balance.
Dyntopo - Remeshes the mesh wherever you sculpt. Slow, only use in specific scenarios
Remesh - Remeshes the whole mesh to a certain voxel size that you determine. Best for sculpting objects that you're making big changes on constantly.

There are some other ways to subdivide the mesh that are more for the "Cleaned up" phase of sculpting.
QuadRemesh - best for getting a "clean" base mesh on a sculpture you've been regularly remeshing.

MultiRes Modifier - Subdivides the mesh in a way optimized for sculpting. Just works by subdividing like a regular SubSurf modifier.

In this case I think you should use the voxel remesh.

